# complex query for gamedatabase

Tags: sql, database

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sq0X-UPIs9Uh0RjGuGpyrSGiod8GXjwJ3--X03xzEnc/edit?usp=sharing

here my gamedatabase schema and I have complex query that I have to do.

: Average age of the customers who bought the top most 3 war games

```
select customer_id,game_id
from purchase mstwg
where game_id = mstwg.game_id
;

create view mstwg As
select game_id, title
from game
where genre='war'
order by sale_quantity desc
limit 3;

create view  personsss As
select customer_id
from purchase,mstwg
where purchase.game_id = mstwg.game_id;


select customer_name
from customer, personsss
where customer.user_id=personsss.customer_id;

select AVG(age)
from customer, personsss
where customer.user_id=personsss.customer_id;
```

I did it with views but it is not allowed. I couldn't find how to write such a query without views.
Can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline views:

```
select customer_id,game_id
from purchase,
   ( select game_id, title
     from game
     where genre='war' ) as mstwg
where game_id = mstwg.game_id;     

select customer_name
from customer, 
    (select customer_id
     from purchase, 
        ( select game_id, title
          from game
          where genre='war' ) as mstwg
     where purchase.game_id = mstwg.game_id) as personsss
where customer.user_id=personsss.customer_id;

select AVG(age)
from customer, 
    (select customer_id
     from purchase, 
        ( select game_id, title
          from game
          where genre='war' ) as mstwg
     where purchase.game_id = mstwg.game_id) as personsss
where customer.user_id=personsss.customer_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd give it a try using [CTEs](https://www.essentialsql.com/introduction-common-table-expressions-ctes/):

```
-- Select the game IDs of the 3 most sold ones
with top_war_games as (
  select game_id
  from game
  where genre = 'war'
  order by sale_quantity desc
  limit 3
),
-- Select the customer IDs of those who bought the above mentioned games
purchases as (
  select customer_id
  from purchase p
  join top_war_games twg on p.game_id = twg.game_id 
),
-- Compute the average of those customers
final as (
  select avg(c.age) 
  from customer c
  join purchases p on c.user_id = p.customer_id
)
select * from final
```